# Yii file field is always empty

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, yii

I add this code to my view:

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,"image:"); ?>
<?php echo $form->fileField($model, 'image'); ?>
```

and this to my CFormModel:

```
public $image;
```

and in the CFormModel rules:

```
array('image', 'file', 'allowEmpty'=>true),
```

and send it by jquery ajax:

```
...
    var dataString=$("#myform").serialize();
    $.ajax({
            dataType:'html',
            url: sendurl,
            data: dataString,
            type: 'post',
...
```

But when i want to reach image element by some thing like

$model->image

It return Empty!! but i can rech other element by $model-> !!

I saw that the Yii add hidden field above of the input file field and when i post data it assume as image field!!!

What is hat hidden field ?

Why i cant reach file field like other fields?

Why my Code don't work ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should use `htmlOptions` something like this:

```
$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
  'id'=>'activity_form', 
  'enableAjaxValidation'=>true, 
  'stateful'=>true, 
  'htmlOptions'=>array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')
));
```

Refer the following link for more details:

> http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-model/

Answer (score 0):

`.serialize()` don't work on file inputs like that. you'll have to use something like [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData)

```
var data=new FormData($("#myform")[0]);
$.ajax({
        dataType:'html',
        url: sendurl,
        data: data,
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,
        type: 'post',
```

http://caniuse.com/xhr2

Comment: "var data=new FormData($("#myform"[0]);" return "NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED: Unexpected error"